# Which text rendering framework should I use?

Tags: ipad, uikit, uiwebview, core-graphics, uitextview

I'm currently scoping out a project for the iPad which is rather text and font heavy. There are many pages of styled text, which also need custom fonts. I have toyed with the idea of simply rendering PDF or PNG files on-screen, but I think we need to be able to dynamically repaginate the text.

We've used UIWebView in a previous project quite successfully, however there are a few things I don't like about it... Firstly, you have to hide all the silly drop shadow elements to stop them showing when the user scrolls beyond the bounds, and we had to add some JavaScript to find out actually when a page had fully loaded. Overall, the experience seemed a bit clunky, as well as worrying if the project could potentially break if Apple decided to update the subviews...

The other thing we've been looking at is Core Text, which looks very powerful. The only worry with this is that it appears to be a rather steep learning curve for us since we've mainly been working in UIKit (with a bit of Core Graphics). I couldn't even work out how to change the size of the font after a morning's work.

Are there any other alternatives*? Should I stick with Core Text? Is there any way of using UITextView with multiple fonts and styles?

Thanks!

:-Joe

EDIT: *by alternatives, I am really looking for built-in iPhone SDK alternatives only please... I would rather not mess with third party frameworks because I don't have the time... Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use Pango, which uses CoreText when on iOS.

Comment: What is Pango? I'd rather not use third-party libraries, because it means added time to the build, especially if things go wrong and I need support...

Comment: Pango is a library for rendering multilingual text, and is used in Linux almost across the board (at least in GTK+ plus more).

Comment: I just want to be able to draw formatted text really. Pango sounds a little overcomplicated for this task. But thanks!